# Counting same containt number from range number without loop in ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, numbers, range

Example: if I have range of numbers from `1..100` and I want to count all numbers which contain 14, I would use:

```
total = 0

(1..100).each do |x|
 if x.to_s.include?("14")
   total += 1
 end
end

puts "total : #{total}"
```

this code works, but how to do this if range of numbers is too long like `(1..1000000000)` or more. Of course this needs long time for calculating total. My question is how to count number with same contain without loop? because in my case I need faster way to get total.

Comment: Suppose the range was `1..100_000` and you were matching with `"33"`. For  `3333.to_s`, would you add `1`, `2` or `3` to the total number of matches?

Comment: no, i'm just want to counting all number containt include 14, example : 

1). (1..100) have 1 containt => [14] 
2). (1..1000) have 20 containt => [14, 114, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147,148, 149, 214, 314, 414, 514, 614, 714, 814, 914]
3. etc ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the range:

```
def str_range(n)
  "1"..(10**n).to_s
end
```

I will address the problem of finding the number of strings within the range that contain the string `"14"` (one or more times).<sup>1</sup> A straightforward way is:

```
def nbr_14s_brute_force(n)
  str_range(n).count { |s| s[/14/] }
end

nbr_14s_brute_force(2) #=>     1
nbr_14s_brute_force(3) #=>    20
nbr_14s_brute_force(4) #=>   299
nbr_14s_brute_force(5) #=>  3970 
nbr_14s_brute_force(6) #=> 49401
```

Now let's look for a way that's more efficient, borrowing from discrete probability theory.

Suppose `n = 2`. Then:

```
str_range(2) #=> "1".."100"
```

Since `"14"` only appears once in the range `"1".."100"`, there is only one (string) element of the range that contains `"14"`.

Now let `cnt_first(n,i)` equal the number of elements of `str_range(2)` which do *not* contain `"14"` when the ten's digit equals `"i"`:

```
cnt_first(2,1) # => 9
cnt_first(2,i) # => 10
```

for `0 <= i <= 9, i != 4`.

Further, let `cnt(2)` denote the number of strings in the range `str_range(2)` that do not contain `"14"`. We have:

```
cnt(2) = (0..9).reduce { |i| cnt_first(2,i) }
  #=> 99
```

It follows that the number of strings that do contain `"14"` equals `100 - cnt(2) #=> 1`.

Now consider `n #=> 3`, where:

```
str_range(3)
  #=> "1".."1000"
```

Of the 1,000 elements in this range, how many elements do *not* contain the string `"14"`?

We can immediately eliminate `"1000"` since `"14"` does not have a zero in the unit's position, so we need only consider the range `"1".."999"`.

Suppose the digit in the first (hundred's) position is `1`. Then strings that do not contain `"14"` must contain a character other than `"4"` in the ten's column. Therefore, the number of two-digit strings beginning with `"1"` that do not contain `"14"` equals:

```
cnt_first(3,1) = cnt_first(2,0) + cnt_first(2,1) + cnt_first(2,2) +
                 cnt_first(2,3) + cnt_first(2,5) + cnt_first(2,6) +
                 cnt_first(2,7) + cnt_first(2,8) + cnt_first(2,9)  

               = (0..9).reduce { |i| cnt_first(2,i) } - cnt_first(2,4)
  #=> cnt(2) - cnt_first(2,4)
  # => 99 - 10 => 89
```

Now suppose the hundred's digit (`i`) does not equal `1`. Then:

```
cnt_first(3,i) = (0..9).reduce { |i| cnt_first(2,i) }
  # => cnt(2) => 99
```

so

```
cnt(3) = 10 * cnt(2) - cnt_first(2,4)
  #=> 10 * 99 - 10 => 980
```

meaning that there are `1000 - 980 #=> 20` numbers in the range `"1"-"1000"` that do not contain `"14"`. This is confirmed by the earlier "brute force" calculation.

It is seen that the steps for calculating `cnt(4)` are the same as for calculating `cnt(3)`.

For `i = 1`:

```
cnt_first(4,1) = cnt(3) - cnt_first(3,4)
```

For `i != 1`:

```
cnt_first(4,i) = cnt(3) => 980
```

so

```
cnt(4) = 10 * cnt(3) - cnt_first(3,4)
  #=> 10 * 980 - 99 => 9800 - 9701
```

so for `n => 4` there `10000 - 9701 #=> 299` strings that do not contain `"14"`, which again is confirmed by the earlier calculation.

If the reader is not convinced, this can be easily proved by induction.

A simple recursive method can be used to compute the desired result:

```
def nbr_14s_smart(n)
  10**n - recurse(n).first
end

def recurse(n)
  if n == 2
    puts "2: 1"
    [99, 10]
  else 
    cnt, cnt4 = recurse(n-1)
    new_cnt, new_cnt4 = 10 * cnt - cnt4, cnt
    puts "#{ n }: #{ 10**n - new_cnt }"
    [new_cnt, new_cnt4]
  end
end

nbr_14s_smart(10)
  #  2: 1
  #  3: 20
  #  4: 299
  #  5: 3970
  #  6: 49401
  #  7: 590040
  #  8: 6850999
  #  9: 77919950
  # 10: 872348501
  #=> 872348501
```

```
1Only minor modifications are required to replace "14" with the string representation of an
arbitrary two-digit number, but the exposition is easier to follow by hardwiring the string.
```